# .htaccess URI language code rewrite for Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a site that functions using a "language" URI attribute to set language

```
oursite.com/home?language=en
```

We need to be able to also use SEO friendly 2 character URI preppenders

```
oursite.com/en/home
```

I'm currently doing a redirect to the index.php file in .htaccess with a few exceptions so my .htaccess has these 2 lines for rewrites

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2})/(.*)? ?$2/language=$1
RewriteRule !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt) /index.php?/$1
```

I need to do a logical rewrite to end up with

```
/index.php?/home?language=en
```

What would be the correct Rewrite rule set to make this happen?  Is it really even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RewriteRule !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt) /index.php?/$1` line isn't going to work because you can't create a backreference to a negative match.

Also, a request like: `/index.php?/home?language=en` is kind of ambiguous, the `?` is reserved and needs to be encoded in the query string, otherwise, it can be appended (so that `?` becomes a `&`). Try something like:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2})/(.*)? /$2?language=$1 [L]
RewriteRule !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt) /index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

This takes: `http://oursite.com/en/home` and rewrites it internally to the URI `/index.php?/home&language=en`. But if you literally want an encoded `?` in the query string then change the second rule to:

```
RewriteRule !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt) /index.php?%{REQUEST_URI}\%3F%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NE]
```

Comment: I tried both solutions, but still no luck.  I understand that the double '?' seems odd, but Codeigniter handles it well (captures the slashed URI segments and passes the rest as traditional $_GET array).

Comment: @BayssMekanique I left out a backslash before the `%3F` in the second rule because it would otherwise be interpreted as a backreference. Also, I've tested both rules in a new install of apache and an index.php that prints out the SERVER and GET arrays: [First Rule output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PFxZj.png) and the [Second Rule output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2MRF5.png) (you can see which rule is being used in the emacs window on the right)

Comment: It still doesn't work, but I'm almost certain it has to do with how CI is manipulating the URI.

`/admin/products?language=es` produces: `array(1) { ["/admin/products?language"]=> string(2) "es" }` which works fine.

`/es/admin/products` produces: `array(1) { ["/admin/products?language"]=> string(2) "es" }` which doesn't work.  I'm not sure where the issue is :-/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the first rule.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2})/(.*)? /index.php?/$2?language=$1
```

As for the second rule (for the urls without a language prefix), you could do something like this. As like Jon said, you can't backreference a negative match.

```
RewiteCond $1 !^index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?/$1
```